# A hosted asp.net mvc application is throwing on Startup.ConfigureAuth

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have an application that works fine in my dev machine, but when hosted in a third-party hosting provider, it throws an exception on Startup.ConfigureAuth method, here is the stack trace.

```
[NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.]
   Jobatease.Web.Startup.ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app) +899
   Jobatease.Web.Startup.Configuration(IAppBuilder app) +5

[TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.]
   System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor) +0
   System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.UnsafeInvokeInternal(Object obj, Object[] parameters, Object[] arguments) +92
   System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture) +101
   Owin.Loader.<>c__DisplayClass12.<MakeDelegate>b__b(IAppBuilder builder) +66
   Owin.Loader.<>c__DisplayClass1.<LoadImplementation>b__0(IAppBuilder builder) +123
   Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.<>c__DisplayClass2.<InitializeBlueprint>b__0(IAppBuilder builder) +71
   Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.OwinAppContext.Initialize(Action`1 startup) +462
   Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.OwinBuilder.Build(Action`1 startup) +40
   Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.OwinHttpModule.InitializeBlueprint() +70
   System.Threading.LazyInitializer.EnsureInitializedCore(T& target, Boolean& initialized, Object& syncLock, Func`1 valueFactory) +115
   Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.OwinHttpModule.Init(HttpApplication context) +106
   System.Web.HttpApplication.RegisterEventSubscriptionsWithIIS(IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context, MethodInfo[] handlers) +534
   System.Web.HttpApplication.InitSpecial(HttpApplicationState state, MethodInfo[] handlers, IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context) +172
   System.Web.HttpApplicationFactory.GetSpecialApplicationInstance(IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context) +339
   System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.InitializeApplication(IntPtr appContext) +296

[HttpException (0x80004005): Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.]
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.FirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +9946024
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.EnsureFirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +90
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate(IIS7WorkerRequest wr, HttpContext context) +261
```

Please any help as to the cause of this exception will be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Have you debugged it on the third-party hosting provider?

Comment: @Callum nope, but trying to do that now.

Comment: @Cizaphil Find out what's null

Comment: @jumpingcode how should I do that since the application is remotely hosted?

Comment: @Cizaphil Attach a remote debugger